# About Intel 82865g

Tags: unity, graphics, intel-graphics

Well I think this is already been asked but any of those questions did not answer me.
My computer, a HP d260 MT brand machine has the following specs:

- Pentium 4 processor @3.0 Ghz
- On-board Intel 82865G graphics controller @ 96mb
- 1 GB RAM

I have seen many telling that with their Intel 82865G graphics they are able to run ubuntu 13.04 but I tried ubuntu 11.04 on my computer last year and its desktop screen was not showing and unity was not working

Please help me.

Comment: Uninstall unity and try some lightweight WM like fluxbox or try [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add some RAM.  Do you know how fast the RAM is in terms of MHz?

Comment: in CPU-Z it shows DRAM frequency 199.5 MHz

Comment: That may be your issue.  You may want to upgrade it with higher speed RAM. 2GBs should be fine, as long as it's faster.  Or, you could upgrade to a new system completely, as it is a bit outdated.
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=2gb%20ram&sprefix=2gb+r%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A2gb%20ram

Comment: can i have intel 82865g drivers on xubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu should install on your computer and it will also run, but the performance won't be good. Why do you want to install Ubuntu 13.04? In order to continue to get software updates, you'll have to reinstall or upgrade the operating system at the end of the nine-month term of support. A Long Term Support release such as Ubuntu 12.04 which has a five-year term of support, or Xubuntu 12.04 which has a three-year term of support would be better. For better performance select Xubuntu 12.04.

Comment: could you tell me why in my ubuntu 11.04 unity was not working

Comment: can you tell me if xubuntu has all features of ubuntu . I don;t need themes or unity

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 has reached End of Life, so it's difficult to install any packages or update it. Regarding your hardware, your RAM is very slow and you may have a problem using Unity's 3D interface. Xubuntu uses a 2D XFCE desktop environment. 2D should work better with your hardware than 3D.